# Shiny: Display textOutput() if input is different from the default value

Tags: shiny, conditional-statements

I have a Shiny App with multiple inputs of different kinds (`checkboxGroupInput`, `sliderInput`, `dateRangeInput` ...) with default selected values.
I am trying to display a text message at the top of my `dashboardBody` if the input values are different from the default ones.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
#one of the inputs
dateRangeInput(
            "date_reception",
            "Sélectionnez une plage de dates",
            start = min(dataset_all$date_reception),
            end = max(dataset_all$date_reception),
          ),
#the output to show if input is different from default
textOutput("warning_filters")


----------


)


server <-  function(input, output) {    

observeEvent(input$date_reception,
                   {
                     if ((input$date_reception[1] != min(dataset_all$date_reception)) |
                         (input$date_reception[2] != max(dataset_all$date_reception))) {
                       output$warning_filters <-
                         renderText({
                           "Warning: filters apply"
                         })
                     } else{
                       NULL
                     }
                   })
}
```

My issue is that the message is correctly displayed when I change one of the dates but does not disappear when I select again the default value (here, `min(dataset_all$date_reception)` or `max(dataset_all$date_reception)`).
I have tried playing with `ignoreNULL` and `ignoreInit` but nothing changed.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-assign `warning_filters` when the condition is false.  Now, the `warning_filters` gets set to the warning text and even though you have the function return `NULL` when the condition doesn't hold, you don't actually change the values of `warning_filters`.  The code below should work.

```
observeEvent(input$date_reception,
                   {
                     if ((input$date_reception[1] != min(dataset_all$date_reception)) |
                         (input$date_reception[2] != max(dataset_all$date_reception))) {
                       output$warning_filters <-
                         renderText({
                           "Warning: filters apply"
                         })
                     } else{
                       output$warning_filters <- NULL
                     }
                   })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for spotting this _quite silly_ mistake.